# Inserting treeNodes from array causes "empty" nodes to be inserted

Tags: c++, data-structures

The intent of my code is import treeNodes from an array. The problem with this is that even though I made sure to set root->left and root->right as NULL when I create new treeNodes.

**When I traverse the tree and end up at the tree's leaves, the left and right members are still NOT NULL.**

```
treeNode* import_treeNode(treeNode* root, int nodes[], int curr_i, int size){
    if (curr_i < size){
        treeNode* newNode = new treeNode;
        root = newNode;
        root->value = nodes[curr_i];
        if (2 * curr_i + 1 < size){
            root->left = import_treeNode(root->left, nodes, 2 * curr_i + 1, size);
        } else {
            root->left = NULL;
        }
        if (2 * curr_i + 2 < size){
            root->right = import_treeNode(root->right, nodes, 2 * curr_i + 2, size);
        } else {
            root->right = NULL;
        }
        return root;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like your default constructor doesn't initialize the values... Make sure all of your private variables are initialized... Especially when you are doing just `treeNode() = default;` for constructor declaration...

Answer (score 0):

When you assign to the root:

```
root = newNode;
```

You are losing the root node that is passed to the function. So for example here:

```
root->left = import_treeNode(root->left, nodes, 2 * curr_i + 1, size);
```

The root-left that you pass to the recursive call in not valid.

Perhaps you can use the `newNode` throughout the function instead of assigning it to the root and using the root.

Comment: I apologize. I should have been more clear in my description. My nodes are being successfully inserted but I get ghost nodes where there shouldn't be. These empty/ghost nodes would have its value set at 0, but nowhere in my constructor do I ever set the left/right nodes of a given node to take value 0. For example, I specifically do if (2 * curr_i + 1 < size){...} to ensure that the potential left node would be valid, if not, set this field to NULL. But instead of NULL, it still returns a node with value 0.

Comment: Actually your code works, maybe you have a bug in traversal code.